# Searching for parent records whose children meet predicate

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have a parent and child database, and the child keeps a sort of running transcript of things that happen to the parent:

```
create table patient (
   fullname text not null,
   admission_number integer primary key
);

create table history (
   note text not null,
   doctor text not null,
   admission_number integer references patient (admission_number)
);
```

(Just an example, I'm not doing a medical application).

`history` is going to have many records for the same `admission_number`:

```
admission_number      doctor    note
------------------------------------
3456                  Johnson   Took blood pressure
7828                  Johnson   EKG 120, temp 99.2
3456                  Nichols   Drew blood
9001                  Damien    Discharged patient
7828                  Damien    Discharged patient with Rx
```

So, my question is, how would I build a query that let me do and/or/not searches of the note field for `patient` records, like, for example, if I wanted to find every patient whose history contained "blood pressure" and "discharged".

Right now I'm been doing a `select` on `history` that groups by `admission_number`, combining all the notes with a `group_concat(note)` and doing my search in the `having`, thus:

```
select * from history 
  group by admission_number
  having group_concat(note) like '%blood pressure%' 
     and group_concat(note) like '%discharged';
```

This works, but it makes certain elaborations very complicated -- for example, I'd like to be able to ask things like "every patient whose history contains "blood pressure" and whose history with Dr. Damien says "discharged," and building qualifications like this on top of my basic query is very messy.

Is there any better way of phrasing my basic query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to your `EXISTS` method, but computes the subqueries differently.
This might or might not be faster, depending on how your tables and indexes are organized, and on the queries' selectivity.

```
SELECT *
FROM patient
WHERE admission_number IN (SELECT admission_number
                           FROM history
                           WHERE note LIKE '%blood pressure%')
  AND admission_number IN (SELECT admission_number
                           FROM history
                           WHERE note LIKE '%discharged%'
                             AND doctor = 'Damien')
```

Alternatively, you could use a [compound subquery](http://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound) (computing the intersection once is likely to be faster than executing `IN` twice for every record):

```
SELECT *
FROM patient
WHERE admission_number IN (SELECT admission_number
                           FROM history
                           WHERE note LIKE '%blood pressure%'
                           INTERSECT
                           SELECT admission_number
                           FROM history
                           WHERE note LIKE '%discharged%'
                             AND doctor = 'Damien')
```

Comment: I like the second one, though a problem with using the compound ops is that you can't group `UNION`/`INTERSECTION`/`EXCEPT` with parenthesis, they group from left to right obligatorily -- if you keep your AND/OR/NOT logic in the `WHERE` clause then you can recourse to parentheses to control applicative order.  I was avoiding them for this reason but this is a good solution.  I'll def profile both.

Comment: Actually I think I'll try your first one too; it might actually be the most elegant from the perspective of the query generating code -- it lets you convert primitive comparison predicates into fully-formed `SELECT` statements that don't need to know anything about the `FROM` table.  And then the generator can just glue these together with the proper AND/OR/NOT and parens.

Comment: You can use parentheses with an extra `SELECT`, i.e., `SELECT * FROM ... EXCEPT SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ... UNION SELECT * FROM ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a `JOIN` operation?

e.g.
considering, the patient table contains the following data:

```
INSERT INTO patient VALUES('Bob', 3456);
INSERT INTO patient VALUES('Mary', 7828);
INSERT INTO patient VALUES('Lucy', 9001);
```

**Running the query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.fullname, p.admission_number FROM patient p
INNER JOIN history h ON p.admission_number = h.admission_number
WHERE note LIKE '%blood pressure%' OR note LIKE '%Discharged%';
```

gets you:

```
fullname = Bob
admission_number = 3456

fullname = Lucy
admission_number = 9001

fullname = Mary
admission_number = 7828
```

**And running the following query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.fullname, p.admission_number FROM patient p
INNER JOIN history h ON p.admission_number = h.admission_number
WHERE note LIKE '%blood pressure%';
```

gets you:

```
fullname = Bob
admission_number = 3456
```

Comment: This works for a single search predicate `note LIKE '%blood pressure%'`.  The problem is searching for two predicates combined with an AND, like `note == 'a' and note == 'b'` -- if we did it in your WHERE clause, we'd never find any records, because both tests would be acting against the same record.  What we want is to find patient records where one related note == 'a', AND ANOTHER note == 'b'.

Answer (score 1):

I have something -- using `EXISTS` to construct these is a bit cleaner:

```
select * from patients where 
    exists ( 
      select 1 from history where
        history.admission_number == patients.admission_number
        AND
        history.note LIKE '%blood pressure%'
    )
    AND
    exists (
        select 1 from history where
        history.admission_number == patients.admission_number
        AND 
        history.note LIKE '%discharged%'
        AND
        history.doctor == 'Damien'
    );
```

That's much better, now I can construct really fine-grained predicates.